# Can I set a default LIMIT for all selects in the MySQL client?

Tags: mysql

I am making queries in the MySQL client (command line).

Is there a way to set a default LIMIT for SELECT queries? It's tiresome to type each time, and if I forget it, I sometimes end up with thousands of results that I didn't want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Set the `select-limit` variable, either by passing it on the command line:

```
mysql --select-limit=1000
```

or by setting it in `~/.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
select-limit = 1000
```

You can also set `select-limit` by setting the `safe-updates` option to `1`, which will also prevent you from running `UPDATE` or `DELETE` queries which do not involve a key constraint. (This is a useful way of preventing certain common, dangerous mistakes.)

Comment: Looks like just what I need. But for some reason it's not picking up my ~/.my.cnf settings. Let me check it out and get back to you...